Ошибка Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()
Не могу подключить базу данных к сайту. При попытке подключить БД выдаётся такая ошибка:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in D:\Проекты\Новая папка\index.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\Проекты\Новая папка\index.php on line 11

У меня OC Windows 11
Вот мой код:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Не работает php</p>
    <?php
    $connection=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'data');
    $sql = "SELECT Name FROM tablical";
    $massive=mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($massive);
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        print_r($value);
    }
    ?>



</body>
</html>


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Никогда не используй в путях пробелы и нелатиницу.

Расширение не включено, или не установлено. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281467/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-connect

удивительно, но готового ответа для винды я не нашёл

Эта ошибка означает, что расширение mysqli не установлено.

если вы не сами устанавливали РНР, а используете какую-то сборку или панель управления, то ищите, как в этой панели включить расширение mysqli
если устанавливали сами, то

под Windows в папке, где установлен РНР, надо найти файл php.ini (если его нет, то переименовать php.ini-development в php.ini) и там раскомментировать строчку extension=mysqli
под Ubuntu делаем sudo apt install php-mysqli (или phpX.X-mysqli если используется определённая версия)
под остальные ОС гуглите инструкцию



После этого перезапустить веб-сервер

Раскомментировал, не помогло

Во-первых, надо перезапустить веб-сервер. Во-вторых, надо убедиться, что это нужный php.ini. В третьих, читаем пункт про панель управления.

Я Всё сделал в точности как вы и сказали, но мне не помогло

Я пользуюсь xampp, возможно в нём проблема?

Вы сделали всё РОВНО НАОБОРОТ

Читаем снова если вы не сами устанавливали РНР, а используете какую-то сборку или панель управления, то ищите, как в этой панели включить расширение mysqli
